# MySQL Selecting, Ordering by DESC, and getting specific indexes

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have quite a large MySQL table (about 15,000+ rows) and I'm looking for a way to perform the following query, but in a more efficient way:

```
SELECT col, otherCol, theOtherCol 
FROM table 
WHERE anotherCol > 0 
ORDER BY ohACol DESC
```

This query uses up way too much RAM on my VPS, which I can understand as it's selecting over 15,000 rows. I do know which 5 indexes I need out of the 15,000+ (after sorted in DESC order). How can I only get those 5 into my result set, instead of all 15,000?

Comment: 15k rows is nothing. Do you have defined indexes on some columns? And add a `limit 5` to the end of your query if you only need 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use paginated query to limit the amount of data you send to your application server. See [Using MySQL LIMIT to Constrain The Number of Rows Returned By SELECT Statement](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx). For example if your page size is 100 then the first page's result can be fetched with:

```
SELECT col, otherCol, theOtherCol 
FROM table 
WHERE anotherCol > 0 
ORDER BY ohACol DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The second page's with:

```
SELECT col, otherCol, theOtherCol 
FROM table 
WHERE anotherCol > 0 
ORDER BY ohACol DESC
LIMIT 100, 100;
```

The third:

```
SELECT col, otherCol, theOtherCol 
FROM table 
WHERE anotherCol > 0 
ORDER BY ohACol DESC
LIMIT 200, 100;
```

So you would have to control the pagination in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the desired indexes you can add a constraint to the WHERE clause:

```
 WHERE indexCol IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't know what would be the desired indexes, just the index number such as indexes `20`-`25`

Comment: The condition I provided allows you to specify those numeric indexes.

Comment: Though, if they're always going to be grouped, using an inequality such as: `indexCol >= 20 AND indexCol <= 25` would be preferable.

Comment: oh ok, so if I were to use `WHERE indexCol IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 24)`, it would get the 20-24th rows in the table, right?

Comment: That will work, yes, though I'd recommend inequalities if they're in a group. Either will produce the desired results, though.

Comment: Thank you for the help but cdaiga's answer seems to be working for me :)